# Quick Sort using slicing of list or array

Tags: python

My code for quick sort using slicing --

*
    def partition(a):

```
    length=len(a)
    c=0
    piv=a[0] 
    #print(piv) 
    for i in range(0,length):
        if a[i]<piv:
            c+=1
    a[c],a[0]=a[0],a[c]
    piv=c
    a[piv]

    i=0  
    j=length-1 
    while i<j:
        if a[i]<a[piv]:
            i=i+1
        elif a[j]>a[piv]:
            j=j-1
        else: 
            a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]
            i=i+1 
            j=j-1
    return piv

def result(a1,a2,a,pivot):
    for i in range(0,pivot):
        a[i]=a1[i]

    j=0 
    for i in range(pivot+1,len(a2)):

        a[i]=a2[j]
        j+=1

def quick_sort(a): 

    le=len(a) 
    if le==1 or le==0:
        return a 

    pivot=partition(a)
    #a[pivot]=ap    
    a1=a[0:pivot]
    a2=a[pivot+1:]
    quick_sort(a1) 
    quick_sort(a2) 
    result(a1,a2,a,pivot)
#a=[30,2,4,1,5,102,101,104]
#a=[101,19,113,114,98,100,99,103,104,109]
a=[100,98,93,96,99,92,91]     
res=quick_sort(a)
print(a)
```

Output of this is -->
[91, 92, 93, 96, 98, 92, 100]

If I don't use slicing and update index as usual then it works fine but please correct this code. Why it is not giving the correct output and answer only after checking the code.

Comment: How do you imagine two returns at the end of `quick_sort` are going to work? The second one is never reached…

Answer (score 0):

@Błotosmętek's comment is correct - you would need to invoke the two recursive calls without returning their values, so that both calls are reached.

There is a more fundamental problem in your code, though. Inside `partition` you perform quick-sort operations *in place* as you should be doing, but in your recursive calls, you actually build ***new*** lists, and operate on them, instead of on the list you received as input. This means that the list you received as input would not be affected by the recursive calls. In Python, an expression like `l[s:e]` generates a new list, occupying separate memory locations than `l`.

Your recursive calls should include pointer to the start and end positions of the list (`i` and `j`, in your case), on which you want to operate, not a list argument.